# Socket programming - C - choosing connection

Tags: c, sockets, select, network-programming, webserver

I am trying to do a web server that will provide a set of questions (poll) to the users trying to connect to it.

The only issue is that I do not want to send everyone the questions, I would like to choose which connections to accept. (for example, a simple algorithm that chooses only even numbered connections, in the order they connect). To the other ones I would send a message saying you have not been picked.

I am using select() function to handle multiple connections.

Any ideas on how I can choose this? Good to mention that I am doing this in C language.

Comment: Are you doing this in C or C#?

Comment: Why did you tag this as C#, then?

Comment: To send the others a message, you would have to accept the connection first, wouldn't you? Maybe you should elaborate a bit more and add some examples or existing code for what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can not skip a connection without accepting it, as they are queued by TCP protocol stack. What you'd have to do is to accept the connection, send an error message and than close the connection.

Comment: ok, fair enough, so the solution would be to accept every connection and just send error messages to the clients I do not want to make the poll.